# can't use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger library

Tags: .net, swagger, .net-5

when trying to implement the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger library, gets an error Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Operation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" when using "Operation"

I'm using .net 5

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tycu3.png)
[library implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9lWi.png)

how can i fix this, as the library is already installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the class `Operation` with `OpenApiOperation` like this:

```cs
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
```